# For Loop in a Data Frame to find near duplicate rows

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, hash, duplicates

I have a list of values like this:

```
l = [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0]
```

and I'm trying to find  near duplicate rows(with one or two digit difference) in a dataframe like below:

But please keep in mind that they are many more rows and column and this is just a sample dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0, 1, 0], 'b': [0, 1, 0], 'c': [1, 1, 0], 'd': [1, 0, 1], 'e': [1, 1, 0],
                   'f': [0, 1, 1], 'g': [0, 1, 0], 'h': [1, 1, 0], 'i': [1, 1, 0], 'j': [0, 1, 1]},
                 index=['x', 'y', 'z'])

   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
x  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0
y  1  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1
z  0  0  0  1  0  1  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: You can try using drop_duplicates function https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html and if you want to keep them you can use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

Comment: what do you want to do identify duplicates, drop duplicate or a loop in the dataframe ?

Comment: @Michał Thanks for the answer, I would like to keep near-duplicate rows(with one or two-digit difference with the list that I wrote above )

Comment: @DataSciRookie I would like to keep near-duplicate rows(with one or two-digit difference with the list that I wrote above )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.eq(l).sum(axis=1)` to compute the number of (aligned) common elements with your list:

```
l = [0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0]
df.eq(l).sum(axis=1)

x    6
y    4
z    4
dtype: int64
```

To filter with a threshold, use:

```
diff = 4
df[df.eq(l).sum(axis=1).ge(len(l)-diff)]
```

output:

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j
x  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  0
```